# Fixing circular dependancy when using $http inside the overriden $exceptionHandler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have overriden the $exceptionHandler by injecting $http. I do this because I log an arror to the server.

```
Module.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$http', function ($http) {
    "use strict";
//code
}
```

However I also have an interceptor to add the my $httpProvider:

```
Module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('special-http');
    }]);
```

And this is the interceptor (which I wrapped in a factory):

```
Module.factory('special-http', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  "use strict";

  return {
    'request': function(config) {

      if ($templateCache.get(config.url)){
        return config;
      }

     //some logic

      return config;
    }
  }
}]);
```

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

after fixing the name of '$http '

I now get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20%24exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20%24rootScope
```

Comment: It might be a silly thing but isn't there a space in the string " $http" in the factory definition?

Comment: @Wawy if it is I'm gonna blush..

Comment: @Wawy thanks, can you check out my edit regarding the **circular dependancy**

Comment: http depends on exceptionHandler already,you cant inject http into exceptionHandler .

Comment: @mpm ah.. so any ideas what approach I need to log to the server on error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inject `$injector` to get `$http` later:

```
Module.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
    "use strict";

    return function (exception, cause) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        // code
    };
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/xzDVe/1/)

Comment: i'm pretty sure you'll get exactly the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I've been running this in production for months :)

Comment: @khellang impressive many thanks Kristian! Happy angular coding!

Comment: for some reason my http from the injector doesn't have the always method  **http.post(error_url, data).always(** . nb I'm using angular 1.2.1

Comment: That's weird. It's been there [since 1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6605adf). It should behave exactly the same as when you're injecting it directly.

Comment: Looks like `always` was renamed to `finally` [in this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f078762d48d0d5d9796dcdf2cb0241198677582c) back in 1.2.0 :)

Comment: When trying to fix this problem, be sure to call $injector.get()  **inside** the closure you are returning! Otherwise you will still get the cdep error!

Comment: @fatmatto: Thanks for your comment. It helps me a lot.